# Spring Cloud Config with Git encrypt/decrypt per application

Tags: git, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

Instead of being able to encrypt/decrypt secrets across **ALL** apps, is it possible to encrypt/decrypt the secret differently for each app so that one app cannot know the secrets of other apps?

I know I can use Spring Security to disable encrypt/decrypt endpoints but you would still need it to encrypt and decrypt secrets when you want to update it in git. I want that only teams having access to certain app able to know the secrets and no one else.